# Null and not null values in the same parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this:

```
Decalre @param int
select * from table where param = @param
```

sometimes people would like to select records where param is null.

so, something like this:

```
if @param is null
begin
select * from table where param is null
end
else select * from table where param =@param
```

Is it possible to incorporate this in a single query?

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to cover it off in a where clause:

```
select * from table where (param =@param) or (param is null and @param is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would use the coalesce to replace the null value, will act better on performance than the `or` i think :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Coalesce(@param, 1) = Coalesce(param, 1)
```

Comment: The second argument to Coalesce in each case must be a value that does not appear in the _param_ column, otherwise you'll end up with rows where the _param_ column is null or equal to the second argument. E.g.:

CREATE TABLE #MyTable ([Param] int);
INSERT INTO #MyTable ([Param]) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO #MyTable ([Param]) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO #MyTable ([Param]) VALUES (NULL);


DECLARE @param int;
SELECT *
FROM #MyTable
WHERE COALESCE(@param, 1) = COALESCE([Param], 1);

Result:
1
NULL

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow removed the formatting was removed from my example SQL in the last comment :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  * 
from table 
where (@param is null AND param is null) OR (@param is not null AND param = @param)
```